# Calculating periods for Walk-Forward validation for time series data

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, optimization

I am attempting to calculate the size of sample periods for walk-forward validation. I need to make this calculation given a configurable number of folds and a configurable total period length.

For instance, given folds 2 and total days 3, the sample period would be 2 days with the second day overlapping on both samples. For total days of 7 and folds of 3, then the sample period size should be 3 days with overlap between the first and last day of each period. Any remainder from dividing the total period by folds can be added to the last sample period.

Is there a suitable algorithm for calculating the ideal fit for the sample periods in all cases?